# An Alternative to Views?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am just reading [**this**](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx) article and I came across this:

> Filter: Remove any functions in the
>   WHERE clause, don't include **views** in
>   your Transact-SQL code, may need
>   additional indexes.

If I do not use views, what are the alternatives? I mean, in my situation, I want to select some data from a table and then use a few other select queries to work on the subset of data from the first select query?

How can I do this efficiently?

Thanks all

Comment: More specifics please. Out of context, that quote is meaningless.

Comment: Views on top of views is bad(tm), but views are OK.  It's ambiguous, because it's the SQL for the view that matters.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had linked to the article. Now I have.

Comment: It actually says `don't use any wiews` which is something entirely different...

Comment: It's a 4 years old article. Are you even sure that the things mentioned apply to your version of SqlServer (which is, by the way?).

Comment: @ck: yeah took me a long time to find the quote because of the typo

Comment: Entirely different? Want to shed some light on that?

Comment: Are you actually **having** a performance problem? Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @klausbyskov - I am using SQL Server 2005 and 2008. Do they apply to these versions?

Comment: @Abs: See here: http://apps3.fao.org/wiews/wiews.jsp

Comment: @OrbMan - you misunderstand. When I asked why it was different, I was waiting for another answer within the realms of SQL Server.

Comment: Honestly when I look at advice like this I think that it would also be faster if you don't have any tables in your database and didn't allow connections. It is useful to know such things *if* you have a performance problem to know where to experiment. But to just never use common SQL abilities because they are potentially slower than writing convoluted duplicated code is very bad advice. *Especially* if it is common SQL stuff, each new version will do a better job of optimizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article is misleading without some context.

Red Gate have better articles on [Execution Plans](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/). And a [site search](http://www.simple-talk.com/search/default.aspx?search=execution+plan+basics)

To address what you listed...

- don't use functions on columns on JOINs and WHERE clauses

This is bad: `WHERE DATEADD(day, a, column) = ...`. Moving the DATEADD to the other side is neutral.

- Views are not inherently evil.

Nested views usually are. Indexed views can be very useful.

See my answer and [HLGEMs comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647991/table-valued-udf-vs-views/2648028#2648028)

- use the DMVs and Data Tuning Advisor to look at indexes

SQL 2005+ gives you far better tuning options

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the link on Execution Plans, its much more clearer and indepth than the one I was reading.

Answer (score 5):

Stores procedures and temp tables are a great choice in some situation, and sometimes is the best way.

But sometimes, you can just do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT IdC, Name FROM Customer WHERE ....)
```

that is, you write a query inside the FROM section of the bigger query. I did not like this at first, but with time I realized that some queries are resolved effortless with this.

HTH (Hope This Helps)!

Answer (score 2):

> ...in my situation, I want to select some data from a table and then use a few other select queries to work on the subset of data from the first select query?

This is a little on the vague side, but it sounds like you might be looking for [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), with which you could construct a query such as:

```
WITH First_CTE AS
(
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
    FROM Table
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...
),
Second_CTE AS
(
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
    FROM First_CTE
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...
)
SELECT *
FROM Second_CTE
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

You can chain together as many CTEs as you want.  If you are creating all sorts of ad-hoc views just to make a small handful of queries easier to write, then this would be a better option.  But that's a big "if" - it really depends on what you're using the views for.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with stored procedures and temp tables

Comment: -1: This is ridiculous advice to give without knowing any details.

Comment: @OrbMan, really?  How so?  Clearly the quote, even without the article link, was referring to query optimizations.  Hence, don't use view, nor functions in your where clause.  The OP, then went on to say they do a query, then want to work on that subset.  Hence, use a temp table.  Nothing ridiculous about that at all.

Comment: the OP says *I want to select some data from a table and then use a few other select queries to work on the subset of data from the first select query*. There is no indication of a performance problem, and his statement actually sounds like something that SQL does well in a single query (set based operations). But without more details, *we don't know*. To suggest he jettison functions (no more `GetDate()` for you!) and views, and go to stored procedures/temp tables is premature, and thus bad, advice.